# Playing sound while key is pressed C#

Tags: key, onkeyup

How do I get a sound is playing while key is pressed (for example: a pan flute note in Fl Studio while a keyboard key is pressed), i have my code but the sound only plays the wav length and does not continue playing it, i changed Play with PlayLooping but it doesnt work as I want to.
I want to include that when I press the other keyboard key it doesnt sound in the exactly moment it has to play, there is a milisecond length before it plays.

```
bool playing = false;
    bool _bKeyIsDown = false;
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_bKeyIsDown)
        {

            return;

        }
        _bKeyIsDown = true;
        // play sound;
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
    protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyUp(e);
        _bKeyIsDown = false;
    }
  private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        playing = true;
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.A)
        {

            this.sonido.SoundLocation = @"D1.wav";
            sonido.Play();

        }
        else
                if (e.KeyData == Keys.Z)
        {

            this.sonido.SoundLocation = @"E1.wav";
            sonido.Play();

        }
```